# Is there a workaround for bug 10778 in netbeans (Going from readAccess to writeAccess)?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.4

My Netbeans 7.4 freezes when attempting to open a file (an sql file) and I quote the error log at the bottom of this post. Now, [this bug seems to have been around in one form or another](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10778) for 12 years!! The most recent patch seems to be in a file called [KarmaPreferences.java](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/rev/1da0b654addd). Now, this file seems to be part of a javascript module. It seems like I should be able to simply disable or uninstall javascript support and not have to reinstall netbeans from the nightly build, breaking who knows what else in the process. However, when I attempt to do this from ModuleManager, I am told that a whole bunch of modules that should be completely unrelated will be uninstalled including Ant, Java (seriously?!), Python, Service Registry, and IDE Platform. In the vanilla plugins dialogue, Javascript doesn't even show up as an installed or installable plugin.

So, if I'm willing to get rid of unnecessary modules, what should I uninstall to make Netbeans stop freezing everytime I want to open a file? Or, is the below a red herring and I should look elsewhere for the cause of Netbeans freezing? Thanks.

```
SEVERE [org.openide.util.Exceptions]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WARNING: Going from readAccess to writeAccess through queue, see #10778: http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?
id=10778 
[catch] at org.openide.util.Mutex.enterImpl(Mutex.java:709)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.enter(Mutex.java:641)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeEnter(Mutex.java:619)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:440)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.api.PythonPlatformManager.storePlatform(PythonPlatformManager.java:212)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.api.PythonPlatformManager.getBundledPlatform(PythonPlatformManager.java:98)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.api.PythonPlatformManager.load(PythonPlatformManager.java:176)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.api.PythonPlatformManager.<init>(PythonPlatformManager.java:61)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.api.PythonPlatformManager.getInstance(PythonPlatformManager.java:112)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.project.ui.actions.RunSingleCommand.<init>(RunSingleCommand.java:34)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.project.PythonActionProvider.<init>(PythonActionProvider.java:45)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.project.PythonProject.createLookup(PythonProject.java:95)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.project.PythonProject.<init>(PythonProject.java:72)
        at org.netbeans.modules.python.project.PythonProjectType.createProject(PythonProjectType.java:31)
        at org.netbeans.modules.project.ant.AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.loadProject(AntBasedProjectFactorySingleton.java:264)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.createProject(ProjectManager.java:371)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.access$300(ProjectManager.java:86)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager$2.run(ProjectManager.java:292)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager$2.run(ProjectManager.java:235)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:337)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.ProjectManager.findProject(ProjectManager.java:235)
        at org.netbeans.modules.projectapi.SimpleFileOwnerQueryImplementation.getOwner(SimpleFileOwnerQueryImplementation.java:129)
        at org.netbeans.api.project.FileOwnerQuery.getOwner(FileOwnerQuery.java:102)
        at org.netbeans.modules.java.project.ProjectClassPathProvider.findClassPath(ProjectClassPathProvider.java:68)
        at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.getClassPath(ClassPath.java:628)
        at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.errors.Utilities.getSourceClassPathFor(Utilities.java:73)
        at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.errors.ErrorAnnotator$1.run(ErrorAnnotator.java:315)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
Diagnostic information
```

Comment: I don't understand what norms of conduct I violated that caused the downvote, but I apologize in advance. I hardly every get a question downvoted, and I want to fix whatever is wrong with this one. This is a real problem I'm having that's stopping me cold and I really need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people looking for an answer

I had the same error under windows 8 x64

I just give the netbeans64.exe (netbeans.exe in x86) admin rights in properties menu
and the problem dissapeared.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO KarmaPreferences.java has nothing to do with this, you can see in your stacktrace that there is no mention of javascript.karma. I would think this warning is not the cause of your problem. The stacktrace comes from some Python module, so I would first start be removing the Python plugin to see if it helps.

If not, file a new issue against NetBeans and attached thread dump (see [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/GenerateThreadDump)) from moment of freeze

The stacktrace might not be related at all

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, and I'm trying it right now. I also installed the nightly build with minimal plugins, and that did not change anything. It seems that opening an SQL file in a python project directory always causes the freeze. Opening SQL files in non-project directories does not.

Answer (score 1):

I filed a new issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239131 against the python module.

Please vote there to improve its priority.